# Is it possible to send push notification only to users who have the current install apk?

Tags: android, mysql

I have an Android apk, more than 200 people installed that apk so far, some people uninstalled this apk. Is it possible to mark in MYSQL which user has operational apk on his device? And then have system send push notifications only to those users who have operational apk.

please advise, user status:
[image]

Comment: when any user uninstall apk, then server can't find that device so no notification sends to that user.

Comment: ok thank you Jack, but in admin, we can identify/mark users who have not installed apk? because admin show all users.

Comment: no you can't find any such type of users

Answer (score 0):

If you use GCM notification , so GCM unregister automatically when app uninstall and when reinstall again generate new registeration id for this user . So it's clear you work with registeration ids only

Comment: ok thank you, but tell me is it possible to compare the active list of user with user created in DB?